# How to Handle Alerts Using Headless Browsers (HtmlUnitDriver/Phantomjs Driver)

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs, testng

I am using PhantomJs Driver for Headless Testing , I am getting below exception

**Sample code:**

```
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.UnexpectedAlertBehaviour;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;



public class TestLogin {    
WebDriver d;
@BeforeMethod
    public void launh_Browser() {
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "D:\\Selenium\\driver\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");
         Capabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
         ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setJavascriptEnabled(true);                
         ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);     
         d=new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
    }
    @Test
    public void guru_banking_login_excel() throws Exception {
        d.get("http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/");
        d.findElement(By.name("uid")).sendKeys("TestUser");
        d.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("testpwd");
        d.findElement(By.name("btnLogin")).click();
        try{ 
            Alert alt = d.switchTo().alert();
            String actualBoxMsg = alt.getText(); // get content of the Alter Message
            assertEquals(actualBoxMsg,"User or Password is not valid");
            alt.accept();          
        }
        catch (NoAlertPresentException Ex){ 
            String hometitle=d.getTitle();
            assertEquals(hometitle,"Guru99 Bank Manager HomePage");
  }   
d.quit
}
```

Error Observed :

```
 Exception : org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Invalid Command Method - {"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Cache-Control":"no-cache","Connection":"Keep-Alive","
```

I am trying to handle popup using phantomjs as a driver
 Please help on This .........

Thanks in Advance..!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to take care of a lot of points here in your code :

1. While working with **`PhantomJS`** when you mention **`System.setProperty`** use the following code lines instead :

   ```
   File src = new File("C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");
   System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", src.getAbsolutePath());
   ```
2. **`DesiredCapabilities`** type of objects must be initiated with reference to **`DesiredCapabilities`** class only. So change to :

   ```
   DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
   ```
3. While using **`assertEquals`** use **`Assert.assertEquals`** as follows :

   ```
   Assert.assertEquals(actualBoxMsg,"User or Password is not valid");
   //
   Assert.assertEquals(hometitle,"Guru99 Bank Manager HomePage");
   ```
4. As you are using **`TestNG`**, for **`Assert`**, use **`org.testng.Assert;`** instead of **`static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;`** as an import :

   ```
   import org.testng.Assert;
   ```
5. You need to wrap up the line **`d.quit()`** within a separate **`TestNG Annotated`** function too as follows :

   ```
       @AfterMethod
       public void tearDown() {
           d.quit();
       }
   ```
6. Here is your own code block which executes successfully :

   ```
   package headlessBrowserTesting;

   import java.io.File;

   import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
   import org.openqa.selenium.By;
   import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
   import org.testng.Assert;
   import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
   import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
   import org.testng.annotations.Test;

   public class PhantomJS_webdriver_binary 
   {

       WebDriver d;

       @BeforeMethod
       public void launh_Browser() {
           File src = new File("C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");
           System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", src.getAbsolutePath());
           DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
           ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setJavascriptEnabled(true);                
           ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);     
           d=new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
         }

       @Test
       public void guru_banking_login_excel() throws Exception {
           d.get("http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/");
           d.findElement(By.name("uid")).sendKeys("TestUser");
           d.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("testpwd");
           d.findElement(By.name("btnLogin")).click();
           try{ 
               Alert alt = d.switchTo().alert();
               String actualBoxMsg = alt.getText();
               Assert.assertEquals(actualBoxMsg,"User or Password is not valid");
               alt.accept();          
           }
           catch (NoAlertPresentException Ex){ 
               String hometitle=d.getTitle();
               Assert.assertEquals(hometitle,"Guru99 Bank Manager HomePage");
           }  
       }

       @AfterMethod
       public void tearDown() {
           d.quit();
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: ,I made changes and executed the script ,but still get same above exception at  line :Alert alt = d.switchTo().alert();